# Why does mass make curvature in spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature, mass-energy

According to Einstein's general relativity theory, matter with mass makes curvature in spacetime. The greater the mass, the curvature in spacetime will be greater.

### My questions:

- Why will mass make curvature in spacetime, what is the property of mass that makes spacetime curve
- Is there any relation between the Higgs boson and the Higgs field? Or mass is the form of energy ($E=mc^2$) that makes a curve in spacetime?

Answer (score 8):

> what is the property of mass that make spacetime to curve?

The property of mass that makes spacetime curve is the [stress-energy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor). This includes energy density, momentum density, shear stress, and pressure.

Matter has a lot of mass and therefore also a lot of energy. So it has stress-energy and therefore curves spacetime. However, light also curves spacetime. It has no mass, but it does have both energy and momentum, so it has stress-energy.

Comment: So energy also bent spacetime, is it?

Comment: Energy, momentum, shear stress, and pressure, yes

Comment: @SufiQuader Mass has energy. Energy (and other things) bends spacetime. These ideas match what we see in experiments and observations. If we find contradictory evidence we will have to revise these ideas.

Comment: @JohnDoty What is the mechanism by which stress-energy causes spacetime curvature?

Comment: @Hisham The relationship between stress-energy and spacetime curvature *is* the mechanism as far as we understand it. Perhaps we'll come to a more abstract model someday, but we don't have one now.

Comment: @Hisham that is a different question than the one asked here by Sufi Quader. I would encourage you to post it as an actual question rather than a comment.

Comment: Light (photons) also happens to move at the speed of light, which means that it's hard to get a lot of it in one place at one time, and it rarely hangs around long enough to make much impact.  So, although it does technically make curvature in spacetime, it takes very unusual circumstances to be able to observe/measure it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung that is true. I do not think that we have experimental confirmation of light (not photons) producing the predicted spacetime curvature. (I say not photons because we don't have a theory describing the gravitational effects of quantum mechanical photons, just classical light)

Answer (score 4):

We accept Einstein's theory because it matches what we see in observations and experiments. And that's the "why": there is no other reason.

Comment: There should be always "why" and "how" which endeavor us to make new ideas. This is what science is about.

Comment: @SufiQuader No, science is fundamentally grounded in the phenomena. The new ideas come from new observations of the phenomena, and from attempts to make models that better capture the phenomena.

Comment: @SufiQuader Physics answers the "how" and rarely, if at all, but almost never the "why".

Comment: @Tachyon Almost never? I'd say never, because every purported "why" represents some regularity that we've observed in the phenomena.

Comment: @SufiQuader physics is not religion and even in religion the "why" is a very difficult thing to answer.

Comment: In religion you can't question why, you have to believe everything if it is right or wrong. But physics isn't religion, that's why you can question "why" and "how". Like Newton's question was "why the apple is falling?".

Comment: @SufiQuader *why the apple is falling?* Because gravity. OK. But why gravity? Because spacetime curvature. OK, but why spacetime curvature? You don’t actually get anywhere with this kind of thinking. Where do you think it could possibly stop? The truth is that we know of no reason why the laws of physics could not be *completely different* from what they are (other than that we might not be here to notice them).

Comment: @Ghoster "You don’t actually get anywhere with this kind of thinking." You just went from "why is the apple falling?" to "spacetime curvature", so apparently you *do* get somewhere with this kind of thinking.

Comment: @KrisWalker Yep. Another turtle.

Comment: @SufiQuader You don't seem to be aware of Agrippa's trilemma.

Comment: @KrisWalker indeed, now we know that mass does it [because mass has energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/772894/57343). Now the question is “why does energy curve spacetime?”…

Comment: "Why?" in science is usually asking "what's the mechanism by which".

Comment: @PabloH The "mechanism" is generally a summary of a pattern seen in the phenomena. Nature doesn't tell us about "mechanisms": it shows us phenomena.

Comment: @m4r35n357 The way to avoid the turtles is to understand that the foundations of physics are experiments and observations. Theories are an edifice built on those foundations. The notion of a "fundamental theory" is profoundly anti-scientific.

Comment: @JohnDoty Finding there are turtles depends on looking underneath the elephant

Comment: @JohnDoty For example, this is the only "why" I ever seen from physics from Matthew Schwartz's QFT textbook: https://deeplook.ir/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/Schwartz_M.D._Quantum_Field_Theory_and_the_StandBookZZ.org_.pdf?x54505. Look at page 54 (in the PDF viewer) in the section "3.3.1 Energy-momentum tensor". It talks about "why" energy and momentum are conserved via  Noether’s theorem. At least, that is what the author says.

Comment: @Tachyon Why take Noether's theorem as truth? And, in any case, that doesn't demand gravity.

Comment: @JohnDoty I was merely providing an example that I came across during my reading of a "why" answer in physics. The example I provided was a general one and I am not connecting it to gravity or this question from the OP. You said that why is never answered, but I provided an example of the opposite. Nothing more. Don't take it out of context : )

Comment: @Tachyon But it's not an example of an answer, because Noether's theorem doesn't *explain* anything: it merely summarizes a pattern that is seen in the phenomena.

Answer (score 2):

Curved spacetime accelerates equally all test masses (those small enough any curvature they introduce is negligible). In non-relativistic terms, it exerts a force on each object proportional to its mass. By Newton's third law, the source of such forces must be something that is subject to equal and opposite forces, and so the force between two bodies must be proportional to a product of masses. Putting relativity back in, curvature must in general be due to four-momentum (in fact, not the $1$-tensor four-momentum, but a $2$-tensor called stress-energy).

Since equations don't generally care about the cause-effect distinction, we can compute stress-energy [from a suitable tensorial description of spacetime geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress%E2%80%93energy_tensor#Einstein_field_equations) or vice versa, just as in electromagnetism you can compute charge density from the electric field or vice versa, or in a formulation of Newtonian gravity analogous to Gauss's law from electrostatics you can similarly relate mass density to the gravitational field. Again, this is non-relativistic, but with some care can be used to predict the $1/r^2$ behaviour of Newton's force law.

The above analysis has nothing to do with the Higgs field, which explains some elementary particles' rest mass, but it's stress-energy more generally that causes curvature. Even if those particles had no rest mass, they'd still contribute to stress-energy.